# SharePoint C# Feature with http-Requests

Tags: development, feature, feature-receiver, https

I'm trying to make a http request from a C# feature for sharepoint.
The request is made inside "ItemAdded" function of a List.

The request is made like this:

```
   public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties) {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);

        EventFiringEnabled = false;

        string currentSite = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;

        using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(currentSite)) {
            using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb()) {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate () {
                    try {
                        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com");

                        SPList l = spWeb.Lists["d.3_List"];
                        SPListItem item = l.Items.Add();
                        item["Title"] = "Success";
                        item.Update();

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        SPList l = spWeb.Lists["d.3_List"];
                        SPListItem item = l.Items.Add();
                        item["Title"] = "Exception: " + ex;
                        item.Update();
                    }

                });
            }
        }

        EventFiringEnabled = true;
    }
```

But it always fails with the following error:
[image: Request error]

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, the problem was that I ran the feature in a sandboxed solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a delegate that runs with elevated privileges within your function.  This should allow you to run it.  Give this a try:

EDITED:  Give this a shot.

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties) {
    base.ItemAdded(properties);
    string currentSite = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
    EventFiringEnabled = false;
    using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(currentSite))
    {
        using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate () {
                try {
                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.StackTrace);
                }

            });
        }
    }
    EventFiringEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: When I add this to my code it just skips the whole block, doesn't even enter breakpoints...

Comment: make sure you put in the right place.  If you post more of your code, I might have a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: I added my function to the question as it is now

Comment: You have to open the Site and Web so the Object Model knows what you are giving permissions to, to use the delegate.  I will revise my answer

Comment: Sadly it is still not working. It just skips over everything, even breakpoints. I added my code again as it is now. Somehow Console.WriteLine() is not working, that's why I'm trying to write the results to a list.